# How to test scalaz IO?

Tags: scala, io, sbt, scalaz, specs2

Consider the following IO:

```
val io = (for{
      userChoice <- getChar
    } yield if (userChoice == 'y') putStr("yes") else putStr("no")).flatMap(identity)
```

I am trying to test it like this:

```
    val input: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Array('n', 'n')) // Not sure why I need two of them...
    System.setIn(input)
    val output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(output))
    io.unsafePerformIO()
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in))
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)))
    output.toString ==== "no"
```

I am using specs2 within sbt to test. The first time I run the test, it passes. The second time it fails with `Console has reached end of input` and sbt is in a weird state and I need to kill it.

I suppose there might some kind of interaction with sbt but I don't understand what it is exactly. Is there a better way to test IO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of interactions I think it is worth developing a "mini-language" using [Free monads](http://functionaltalks.org/2014/11/23/runar-oli-bjarnason-free-monad) and have 2 interpreters, one for testing using the `Id` Monad and another one for production using the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Configuring Input](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html#Configuring+Input) in the "Forking" section of the docs:

> By default, the standard input of the sbt process is not forwarded to the forked process. To enable this, configure the connectInput setting:
>
> `connectInput in run := true`